# VB6 function to C#

Tags: c#, function, desktop-application, recordset, vb6-migration

Public function MaxID(ColName as String, Table as String) as long

' Here i make a local Variable 
Dim recset as ADOB.Recordset

set recset =Conec.Execute("Select max(" & Colname & ")+1  as maxno from " & table
end if
Set recset= Nothing
End Function

Comment: Good Day Guys,

I have VB6 Library and Windows Based Application i just want to convert it into C# Language and on C# language i am quite New i just created the SQL Connection string 
but if i want to get data in VB6 i use ADOB.Recordset and i use function like this

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code generator site.  Please try it youself or use an online tool. http://converter.telerik.com

Comment: @KhanBaba 1) the comment you added in your own question, this should have been a part of the question text, 2) You cant ask for a full translation of the function, this doesnt make for a good question, you can ask for a particular part of what you are trying to do and do the rest yourself, your question will soon be deleted, hope you read this before it gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The ADODB Library was replaced with the ADO.Net Library in .Net.
So too move ahead quickly i suggest to use a helper class which nearly will be the same as in ADODB I suggest to find a helper class like [Using SqlHelper class in ASP.Net Tutorial with examples in C# and VB.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-SqlHelper-class-in-ASPNet-Tutorial-with-examples-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx)